# NullPointerException from LocalSessionFactoryBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-4.x

I am using Spring and hibernate together (hibernate 4.0.1 and spring 3.1). I am using the following bean definition in applicatonContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

I am getting the following error while instantiating the bean.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:101)
```

From google search it looks like the defect is in Spring. Is there any solution for this? 
Will downgrading my Hibernate and/or Spring help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* a Spring bug ([SPR-8924](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8924)). It's been fixed for 3.1.1, which isn't out yet.

If you're desperate, you could get the [most recent nightly snapshot](http://static.springsource.org/downloads/nightly/snapshot-download.php?project=SPR) which should have the fix in, but of course the nightly snapshots aren't necessarily stable.

Alternatively, stick with Hibernate 3, which Spring also supports.